# Cant create MongoClient inside a constructor in php

Tags: php, mongodb, helper

I am trying to create instance of MongoClient inside a constructor of a class. I am getting error saying

```
Fatal error: Class 'Rate4Me\API\MongoClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Rate4Me\API\API_Pagination.php on line 18
```

This is the constructor inside a class

```
public function __construct()
{
   new MongoClient();
   echo "constructor";
}
```

Mongo driver is installed, extention is updated.

Able to connect when MongoClient is Instantiated outside the class. Like

```
{
    $m = new MongoClient();
    var_dump($m);
}
```

I am not a php expert. Just started to learn coding in php

Comment: Looks like you use a namespace. Prepend a \ before `MongoClient` so it looks like this `new \MongoClient()`.

Comment: It is namespace issue. Please read this section of php documentation about namespaces: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thanks dude.. it worked out.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are running into this issue. Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.shortname1

Your issue is that, the namespace of your class is `Rate4Me\API`, and when you trying to instantiate an unqualified class (a class that don't starts with a `\`), PHP automatically look for the class from `alias` first, and if not found, it uses the prefix `\Rate4Me\API` to look for the class, which is `Rate4Me\API\MongoClient`, hence it fails, since you don't have this class.

So you should use a fully qualified class if it's not within your package, such as `\MongoClient`, `\MongoId`, `\MongoDate`, etc.